# Image being cropped when inside a Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a page which  contains an image , sometimes the image is too big and is cropped, i tried to add a scroll viewer  but I still can't scroll down to see the rest of the picture

Here is my Code :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
   <Grid>
       <Image Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Source="{Binding photolink}" />
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

How can display all of my elements ?

Comment: Normally, I'd suggest you use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx so that it properly fits. You may find that the ScrollViewer doesn't add enough benefit.

Comment: Maybe the question should be: Why doesn't adding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" to a Grid work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ScrollViewer is a control, not a property, so adding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" wont do it. You need to add the entire ScrollViewer control.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Image Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Source="{Binding photolink}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Strech the picture.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
   <Grid>
       <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding photolink}" />
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I recommand you to read about the [Stretch Enumartion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).